# How do I copy Bones and animations to another model

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing, rigging, bones

So I have two models and they're the same. I just modeled one better but the old one has a complete rig like animations bones etc. I really want to save time and know if it's possible to copy the animations and bones to the new one instead of creating a completely new one.
and How do I do it if it is possible?

Thanks

Comment: if you give the same names to the bones of your new armature you'll be able to use the same action, if this is your question